# Find $x$: $\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt[3]{1-\sqrt{x}}=\sqrt[3]{5}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, fractions

I've seen another equation that I have to solve for $x$.
$$\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt[3]{1-\sqrt{x}}=\sqrt[3]{5}$$
Hint me how I must simplify it and then solve it. I don't have any ideas! :(

Comment: Take a cube of both sides and use the original equation.

Answer (score 10):

Cubing both sides $$5=1+\sqrt x+1-\sqrt x+3\sqrt[3]{5(1-x)}$$

$$\iff\sqrt[3]{5(1-x)}=1$$

Cube both sides

Answer (score 10):

**HINT**

Set $a=\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt{x}}$ and $b=\sqrt[3]{1-\sqrt{x}}$ and note that

$$\begin{align}
a+b&=\sqrt[3]{5}\\
a^3+b^3&=2
\end{align}$$

Further use the binomial expansion of $(a+b)^3$ to get

$$(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)$$

The term $ab$ can be computed by using the first relation. Can you take it from here?